# Make a conditional query in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different spreadsheets `A` and `B` where both of them have a column consisting of server names. Some of the server names are in common and for this I want to make a conditional query in Excel where I first want to check if server names are equal and if so check if a column in `A` consisting of integer values have a limit of 90. If the server has a corresponding integer value greater than 90 I want to give a color fill in one of the B's column. So roughly a python like pseudo-code would look like:

```
for i in range(Spreadsheet A: Column 1):
    for j in range(Spreadsheet B: Column 1):
        if i==j:
            if i.column 2 > 90:
               color fill j.column2 red
            else:
                color fill j.column2 green
```

Comment: This case can be solved entirely with formulas

Comment: I am noob at excel, so I would really appreciate if I got the syntax for excel formula.

Comment: It won't let you do conditional formatting using a formula based on a list of values in a different workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a couple of hours to learn the VBA syntax, so the answer would look like:

```
Sub Patch()

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("Patch")

Dim s2 As Worksheet
Set s2 = Sheets("Report")

For i = 5 To 259
    For j = 2 To 227
        If s1.Cells(i, 1) = s2.Cells(j, 1) Then
            If s1.Cells(i, 7) > 90 Then
                s2.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                s2.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Else
        End If

     Next j
Next i

End Sub
```